# get of HashMap becomes null during iteration

Tags: hashmap

I iterate an HashMap with this method:

```
   public  void printMap(Map mp) {
        Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue() + " " + mp.get("objectId"));
    }
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
```

The result is:

```
Key1 = Value1 objectIDValue
Key2 = Value2 objectIDValue
objectId = objectIDValue objectIDValue
Key4 = Value4 null
Key5 = Value5 null
...
```

Why is mp.get("objectId") becomes null once the key is passed?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look possible unless the pair is deleted by another thread. Is this method called concurrently? If so, pair might be deleted by `it.remove()` since **insertion order** and **iteration order** is not guaranteed to be same for `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a concurrency problem. I would try to use a thread-safe map implementation such as `ConcurrentHashMap`. Also, your method removes the last entry in the iteration, which might change depending on the map implementation you choose.